# Can I redirect users to a specific page after they register?

Tags: drupal, redirect, authentication

I've seen that it is possible to redirect users to a specific page after they log in.

Is it possible to do the same on register?

I also need to put in every case some explanations about the process of register and then redirect the user to the proper page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The [logintobogan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module allows such customization. You could also use `hook_form_alter` on the login and registration forms, to change where the user should be redirected to.

Comment: hook_form_alter ... in which file should I define this? ..I never could define hooks, but it's time to do it I guess..sooner or later

Comment: @PartySoft: You would need to create your own little custom module. If you never done so before, you could checkout the developer handbook on drupal.org

Comment: I do have php background but never developped custom modules, only used in drupal some php little snippets, but I guess I will manage.. thanx for the info

Answer (score 0):

I recommend on a Rules module solution -

- When a user is registered he gets a "new user" role
- All "new user" role users are being redirected on login
- When a "new user" role user is being logged-in, the "new user" role is removed from him

Using Rules module you get lots of flexibility with no need of coding, and you can build very nice behaviors sing it.